# why this program has seg fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am a C++ newbie, not quite understand the destruction workflow of this program, so I write destructor for both classes. But got error...  Do I bother defining the destructor of Node?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// in this case, the BST doesn't have duplicates
class Node
{
public:
    Node* parent;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node() : key(-1), parent(NULL), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
    virtual ~Node() {cout << "destructor of Node" << endl; delete parent; delete left; delete right;}
    void setKey(int k)
    {
        key = k;
    }
    int getKey() {return key;}
private:
    int key;
};


class BST
{
public:
    Node* root;
    BST() {root = NULL;}
    virtual ~BST() {freeNode(root);}
    void addNode(int key)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        root = new Node();
        root->setKey(key);
    }
    else 
        addNode(key, root);
}
Node* findNode(int key)
{
    Node* p = root;
    while (p)
    {
        if (p->getKey() == key)
            return p;
        else if (p->getKey()<=key)
        {
            p = p->right;
        }
        else
            p = p->left;
    }
    return p;
}
void walk(Node* node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        walk(node->left);
        cout << node->getKey() << " " << flush;
        walk(node->right);
    }
}
void deleteNode(int key)
{
    Node* p = findNode(key);
    if (p)
    {
        //case 1: p has no children
        if (!p->right && !p->left)
            p->parent->right == p ? p->parent->right = NULL : p->parent->left = NULL;
        //case 2: p has one child
        else if (!p->left && p->right)
        {
            p->parent->right = p->right;
            freeNode(p);
        }
        else if (!p->right && p->left)
        {
            p->parent->left = p->left;
            freeNode(p);
        }
        //case 3: p has two children
        else
        {
            Node *suc = successor(key);
            exchange(suc,p);
            deleteNode(suc->getKey());
        }

    }
}
Node* min(Node* node)
{
    //empty tree
    if (!node)
        return NULL;
    else if (!node->left)
        return node;
    else
        return min(node->left);
}
Node* max(Node* node)
{
    //empty tree
    if(!node)
        return NULL;
    else if (!node->right)
        return node;
    else 
        return max(node->right);
}
Node* successor(int key)
{
    Node *temp = NULL;
    Node *p = findNode(key);
    //case 1: has a right child
    if (p->right)
        return min(p->right);
    //case 2: does not have a right child
    else
    {
        temp = p->parent;
        while(temp->left != p)
        {
            p = temp;
            temp = temp->parent;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

Node* predecessor(int key)
{
    Node *temp = NULL;
    Node *p = findNode(key);
    //case1: has a left child
    if (p->left)
        return max(p->left);
    //case2: does not have a left child
    else
    {
        temp = p->parent;
        while(temp->right != p)
        {
            p = temp;
            temp = temp->parent;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

private:
void addNode(int key, Node* node)
{
    if (node->getKey() <= key)
    {
        if (node->right)
            addNode(key, node->right);
        else
        {
            Node* leaf = new Node();
            leaf->setKey(key);
            leaf->parent = node;
            node->right = leaf;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (node->left)
            addNode(key, node->left);
        else
        {
            Node* leaf = new Node();
            leaf->setKey(key);
            leaf->parent = node;
            node->left = leaf;
        }
    }

}
void freeNode(Node* leaf)
{
    delete leaf;
}
void exchange(Node *a, Node *b)
{
    int temp = a->getKey();
    a->setKey(b->getKey());
    b->setKey(temp);
}
};

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
int *p = NULL;
delete p;

BST tree;
tree.addNode(8);
tree.addNode(4);
tree.addNode(12);
tree.addNode(2);
tree.addNode(6);
tree.addNode(10);
tree.addNode(14);
tree.addNode(1);
tree.addNode(3);
tree.addNode(5);
tree.addNode(7);
tree.addNode(9);
tree.addNode(11);
tree.addNode(13);
tree.addNode(15);
tree.walk(tree.root);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least the code is clean and commented.

Comment: Why so many down votes? Everyone was a newbie sometime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete parent; delete left; delete right;
```

When you delete an object, its destructor is called. Here, both the left and the right node will delete the current one as they delete their parents. To fix this, simply remove parent deletion.

Comment: Thanks @Don, I have two follow up questions: 1. In my code, the program call the destructor of Node many times according to the output. Why? (What I can think of is that when the main() exits, object tree will be destroyed which will call the destructor of BST. But Node is dynamically allocated, why the Node class's destructor is called?) 2. How should I correctly define the destructor of Node and BST in this case to handle memory free?

Comment: Dynamically allocated objects get destructed, as well. You don't need to delete the parent.

Comment: Thanks @Don, but when is dynamically allocated objects get destructed? I only know that explicitly "delete" will destroy them.

Comment: `new` constructs, `delete` destructs. It's that simple.

Comment: hi Don, my question is, why here the destructor of Node is called? When main exits, object tree is destroyed, so its destructor is called so pointer root is deleted. But why Node's destructor is called?

Comment: `~BST` calls `freeNode`, which calls `delete leaf`, which calls `~Node`.

By the way, to avoid getting your question downvoted, next time use the debugger first, and then if this does not help, explain what you have tried to solve the problem.